# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'Phone_1.jpg'

Tags: python, image

New to coding and don't understand the error I am getting. Included below is my code and the traceback:

```
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # single use of plt is commented out
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw     
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw       

def round_corners(original_image, percent_of_side):
    """ Rounds the corner of a PIL.Image

    original_image must be a PIL.Image
    Returns a new PIL.Image with rounded corners, where
    0 < percent_of_side < 1
    is the corner radius as a portion of the shorter dimension of original_image
    """

    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 15)
    # Opening the file gg.png
    imageFile = ("new.jpg")
    im1=Image.open(imageFile)

    # Drawing the text on the picture
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
    draw.text((0,0), "SAMSUNG",(0,0,255),font=font)
    im1.save("marked_image.png")

    #set the radius of the rounded corners
    width, height = original_image.size
    radius = int(percent_of_side * min(width, height)) # radius in pixels

    ###
    #create a mask
    ###

    #start with transparent mask
    rounded_mask = PIL.Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (127,0,127,0))
    drawing_layer = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(rounded_mask)


    # Overwrite the RGBA values with A=255.
    # The 127 for RGB values was used merely for visualizing the mask

    # Draw two rectangles to fill interior with opaqueness
    drawing_layer.polygon([(radius,0),(width-radius,0),
                            (width-radius,height),(radius,height)],
                            fill=(127,0,127,255))
    drawing_layer.polygon([(0,radius),(width,radius),
                            (width,height-radius),(0,height-radius)],
                            fill=(127,0,127,255))

    #Draw four filled circles of opaqueness
    drawing_layer.ellipse((0,0, 2*radius, 2*radius), 
                            fill=(0,127,127,255)) #top left
    drawing_layer.ellipse((width-2*radius, 0, width,2*radius), 
                            fill=(0,127,127,255)) #top right
    drawing_layer.ellipse((0,height-2*radius,  2*radius,height), 
                            fill=(0,127,127,255)) #bottom left
    drawing_layer.ellipse((width-2*radius, height-2*radius, width, height), 
                            fill=(0,127,127,255)) #bottom right

    # Uncomment the following line to show the mask
    # plt.imshow(rounded_mask)

    # Make the new image, starting with all transparent
    result = PIL.Image.new('RGBA', original_image.size, (0,0,0,0))
    result.paste(original_image, (0,0), mask=rounded_mask)

    return result


def get_images(directory=None):
    """ Returns PIL.Image objects for all the images in directory.

    If directory is not specified, uses current directory.
    Returns a 2-tuple containing 
    a list with a  PIL.Image object for each image file in root_directory, and
    a list with a string filename for each image file in root_directory
    """

    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

    image_list = [] # Initialize aggregaotrs
    file_list = []

    directory_list = os.listdir(directory) # Get list of files
    for entry in directory_list:
        absolute_filename = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        try:
            image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
            file_list += [entry]
            image_list += [image]
        except IOError:
            pass # do nothing with errors tying to open non-images
    return image_list, file_list

def round_corners_of_all_images(directory=None):
    """ Saves a modfied version of each image in directory.

    Uses current directory if no directory is specified. 
    Places images in subdirectory 'modified', creating it if it does not exist.
    New image files are of type PNG and have transparent rounded corners.
    """

    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

    # Create a new directory 'modified'
    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, 'modified')
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except OSError:
        pass # if the directory already exists, proceed  

    #load all the images
    image_list, file_list = get_images(directory)  

    #go through the images and save modified versions
    for n in range(len(image_list)):
        # Parse the filename
        filename, filetype = file_list[n].split('.')

        # Round the corners with radius = 30% of short side
        new_image = round_corners(image_list[n],.30)
        #save the altered image, suing PNG to retain transparency
        new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename + '.png')
        new_image.save(new_image_filename)
```

There is the full code and here is the traceback:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8a0b83840aa4> in <module>()
----> 1 round_corners_of_all_images()

C:\Users\ewainscott2019\Desktop\Computer Science\Semester 2\Image Artist\Image Artist Code.py in round_corners_of_all_images(directory)
    124 
    125         # Round the corners with radius = 30% of short side
--> 126         new_image = round_corners(image_list[n],.30)
    127         #save the altered image, suing PNG to retain transparency
    128         new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename + '.png')

C:\Users\ewainscott2019\Desktop\Computer Science\Semester 2\Image Artist\Image Artist Code.py in round_corners(original_image, percent_of_side)
     20     # Opening the file gg.png
     21     imageFile = ("new.jpg")
---> 22     im1=Image.open(imageFile)
     23 
     24     # Drawing the text on the picture

C:\Users\ewainscott2019\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.pyc in open(fp, mode)
   2270             filename = str(fp.resolve())
   2271     if filename:
-> 2272         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2273 
   2274     try:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Phone_1.jpg'
```

I don't understand my error I have in the code. I have tried receiving help elsewhere but cannot find out anything. This is a school project that is overdue and I need to get it done.

Comment: What do you think it is?

Comment: I have no clue, that it why I have come to this website so hopefully someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: The error message states it pretty clearly: the file 'Phone_1.jpg' does not exist.

Comment: What do you think `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Phone_1.jpg' ` means?

Comment: I do not know why it says "Phone_1.jpg" doesn't exist, that isn't even in my code.

Comment: You haven't shown us all the code, but note that in your traceback, the error occurs when you try opening the image and you pass "new.jpg" to that open line.  I don't know what happens beyond that; it's likely that the error talking about Phone_1 is a hardcoded mistake within Image.pyc.  It's likely that it's not finding new.jpg, and that the error message is erroneous.

Comment: Follow the traceback. It tells you where in your code `Phone_1.jpg` is

Comment: It means Python can't find that file in the directories in which it's looking. Perhaps point her in the right direction with an `os.chdir` or a full path + filename structure, e.g. `'/Users/user/Desktop/Phone_1.jpg'`.

Comment: I fixed the following problem but have encountered a new issue. My new error says that there are too many values to unpack. Not sure what this means.

Comment: It means you need to ask a different question with an [mcve] explaining your new issue and a reference to the exact line in your minimally complete verifiable example that causes the issue.  Of course, by the time you have that example (which is likely only one or two lines long), you will either have a good idea of what is wrong, or be able to find a lot of similar issues here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also - maybe once you get your deadline resolved - since you solved your problem, please be useful to the Stack Overflow community and write up an answer explaining how you did it.  The goal is not to solve your problems with the python interpreter, but to provide a resource for others who come by later and have similar issues.